# SonarQube 3.7 squid rules repository

Tags: sonarqube

When browsing a quality profile, I can't seem to filter out rules covered by the squid plugin specifically.  Under the repository filter, squid doesn't show up as an option (just PMD, Checkstyle, etc).

The reason I'm concerned about this is that the 'avoid use of deprecated method' rule was inactive by default, and I had to try and dig it out by searching in the inactive rules.  Now I'm wondering what other squid rules I'm missing out on.

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID is "squid" and repository name is "Sonar"

Comment: ah...got it.  Thanks for that.  I ran the analysis with the deprecated method rule active, and it didn't pick anything up.  In Eclipse, the java compiler warnings pick up hundreds of them in our project.  Is there anything I could be missing?  Also, does the squid plugin pick up the use of deprecated classed, and constructors as well?  Thanks..

Comment: Please open a new thread of discussion and provide the rule ID as well as some code samples. Thank you

Comment: I am also have problems with the exact same rule.  The rule key is CallToDeprecatedMethod.